# jUnit DataSource issue

Tags: jdbc, junit, datasource

I'm trying to print the database table names, but for some reason I get (below) when I try to test the method

`javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial`

I've looked it up and apparently you have to set up the connection manually in the test class, else it won't work (but again, the topic I've read this was from 2008). Is there any way I could not do that?

```
public class ConnectionPool {
    private static ConnectionPool pool = null;
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

private ConnectionPool(){
    try{
        InitialContext cx = new InitialContext();
        this.dataSource = (DataSource) cx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/tut_web");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionPool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static synchronized ConnectionPool getInstance(){
    if(pool == null){
        pool = new ConnectionPool();
    }

    return pool;
}

public Connection getConnection(){
    try{
        return this.dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionPool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}

public void closeConnection(Connection connection){
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionPool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

Context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
   <Resource name="jdbc/tut_web" auth="Container"
       driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tut_web?autoReconnect=true"
       username="root" password="password"
       maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
       logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true"
       removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

Stacktree:

```
Apr 20, 2018 5:40:11 PM com.vio.db.config.ConnectionPool <init>
SEVERE: null
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in      environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application  resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at com.vio.db.config.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:27)
at com.vio.db.config.ConnectionPool.getInstance(ConnectionPool.java:35)
at com.vio.repository.CRUDReflection.<init>(CRUDReflection.java:27)
at com.vio.service.CRUDReflectionTEST.setUp(CRUDReflectionTEST.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnit4TestMethodAdapter.run(JUnit4TestMethodAdapter.java:107)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:535)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1182)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1033)
```

Comment: are you using Spring?

Comment: No. I'm using servlets

Comment: Your problem is that you are not in a server environment when running JUnit test. From avoid doing this, your initialisation of connection should be centralised. Then you can override it in your test environment for not using context configured in the server.